# Not coherent behaviour of jQuery offset(coords) when called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to position an absolute positioned div using jQuery offset() function.
The idea is to position it at a fixed offset from another element of the DOM. This happens in a quite complex environment with multiple nested divs.

The strange thing that happens is that calling it twice gives two different results. To me it seems there is no reason for this, although I am quite new at jQuery so I could be oversighting something obvious.

I do think that

```
var pos = $(document.getElementById(someElementInTheDOM)).offset();
$(document.getElementById(MyDiv)).offset( pos );
```

should position MyDiv always in the same place, even if I call this code some 10 times. That's what correctly happens in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbqe1j78/14/). Click on the magnifying glass several times, everything is ok.

But as soon as I start adding `display:none` and `display:block` properties the thing gets disrupted. I tried to bring it down to basic and I created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cbqe1j78/12/). To see what I mean press on the magnifying glass, click on the magnifying glass again, click on the magnifying glass once more, close the div by the white "X", click on the magnifying glass once more.

Any clue what's going on?

Comment: just a thought, since you are already using jQuery you might want to look into [jQUery UI](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/), you have dialogs covered there too...

Comment: @Banana I will look at it, thank you. I just feel I should learn jQuery properly before going further and this kind of wierd behaviour is what makes me uncomfortable since it make me think I do not grasp what's going on behind

Comment: try to use jquery `position` instead http://api.jquery.com/position/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to change the order:

```
document.getElementById("iuocboun_filter_window").style.display="block";
$(document.getElementById("iuocboun_filter_window")).offset( pos );
```

instead of

```
$(document.getElementById("iuocboun_filter_window")).offset( pos );
document.getElementById("iuocboun_filter_window").style.display="block";
```

EDIT:

Explanation: The `offset` does not work on hidden elements, thats why you have to make it first visible and than set the offset. ;)

Comment: Works and moreover I got exactly why. Thanks. BTW now that you've pointed it out I find the Note in the API docs.